# Jekyll: Liquid Tags used in Sub-directories

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am trying include a certain markdown file that is in the root directory into another file that is in a sub-directory.

I tried many different syntaxes:

```
{% include_relative ../root/file %}
{% include_relative /../root/file %}
{% include_relative ./../root/file %}
{% include_relative /./../root/file %}
(and others)
```

Is there any way to go back to parent directories in Jekyll using Liquid Tags?

Answer (score 2):

From [jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#including-files-relative-to-another-file).

> For example, if `_posts/2014-09-03-my-file.markdown` uses the
>   `include_relative` tag, the included file must be within the `_posts`
>   directory, or one of its subdirectories. You cannot include files in
>   other locations.